# Just like team_join do we have a team_left event on slack apps?

Tags: slack, slack-api

This question is regarding Event Subscriptions on Slack Applications.

Just like `team_join`, do we have or will we have an event which is triggered when a user is 'deleted' or left the whole team(workspace) something like `team_left`?

I am aware of `channel_left`, `member_left_channel` and `group_left`, but these do not help on my case.

TLDR;
Will it anytime soon be a new event called `team_left`, or what other alternative could help me in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check 'user_change' event https://api.slack.com/events/user_change? The payload contains 'deleted' attribute, if that helps.

Comment: Yea it helps a lot, thank you Suyash!